# Arquillian Tomee failing to start

Tags: maven, testng, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I have a tomee based application which I am testing using arquillian.I am using testNg & have configured tomee to use random ports by adding the following to my pom.xml :

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <tomee.httpPort>-1</tomee.httpPort>
                    <tomee.stopPort>-1</tomee.stopPort>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However if I try to bring up & take down the server multiple times, I am getting the following exception :

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Unable to deploy
    at org.apache.openejb.arquillian.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer.deploy(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.java:165)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.openejb.arquillian.common.TomEEContainer.addServlets(TomEEContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.openejb.arquillian.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer.deploy(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.java:157)
    ...
```

My tommee version is 1.7.2 and open-ejb version is 4.7.2. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I've heard the embedded tomee container has issues, but I've not looked into it at all. Do managed or remote containers work as expected?

Comment: Is there any place that we can see the code? At least the test and the whole pom.xml?

Comment: Please add information on: (a) Which TomEE version (b) Which OpenEJB version you are using (in the original question).

Comment: Have added the version details.

Comment: @SurajMenon Hi, have you been able to solve this? I have the same problem and can't find a solution online.